# Запрос с выводом нескольких таблиц

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос, в котором несколько раз выполняется EXEC. Каждый EXEC возвращает табличные данные. Как мне на клиенте разложить результат по полочкам?

Если я делаю запрос

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
SELECT * FROM MyTable2
```

то на выходе я получу результат, который могу средствами фрэймворка превратить в DataSet. Из датасета я могу достать нужную таблицу так

```
... theDS.Tables["MyTable2"] ...
```

А вот в случае с EXEC я получаю просто пронумерованный список таблиц. А как мне их можно проименовать в самом запросе, чтобы нужный мне вывод имел нужное мне имя? А то по индексам ловить результаты как то ненадежно.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос (в чём сложность). Если запрос состоит из набора select-ов, то, например, данные вынимают в `DataSet` через `DataAdapter`, задавая `TableMappings`. Если у вас запрос состоит из набора exec-ов, то аналогично делается. Или у вас динамически количество результатов может меняться? И добавьте, пожалуйста, тэги .net, c# (это ведь с#?).

Comment: @i-one, EXECи выполняют системные процедуры, которые выводят результат.

Answer (score 1):

Так не получится? Имеется ввиду засунуть сначала во временные таблицы, а потом вывести из них. Структура таблиц должна соответствовать формату вывода из EXEC.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable1(...)
CREATE TABLE #MyTable2(...)

INSERT #MyTable1
EXEC MyProc1

INSERT #MyTable2
EXEC MyProc2

SELECT * FROM #MyTable1 MyTable1
SELECT * FROM #MyTable2 MyTable2
```

Comment: А что, если я не знаю формат вывода из EXEC? Знаю только, что там какая то таблица будет

Comment: @iRumba, предложенным способом никак. insert from exec работает только с четкими структурами.

Answer (score 0):

Может просто добавить колонку в select с наименованием таблицы?

```
select 'MyTable1' TableName,* from MyTable1
select 'MyTable2' TableName,* from MyTable2
```

Comment: Не могу.... сам запрос селект находится внутри хранимки, которую я вызываю... мне ее менять нельзя